# Ansible set_fact from dictionary based on item type

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am reading a dictionary from a Kubernetes config map (`cm_config` below) and am using it to replace variables set in `defaults/main.yml` like this:

```
- name: 'Overwrite defaults'
  set_fact: "{{ item.key }}={{ item.value }}"
  with_dict: "{{ cm_config }}"
```

This works fine as long as the items are simple variables. But as soon as an `item` is another dictionary, I'd like to combine the values.

How can I integrate this into the above task? I thought about running the loop twice, with some kind of type check. Not sure how this would work. Additionally, I believe there might be a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution below to achieve your requirement in a single task whit just a bit of jinja2 templating and a [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html) to get existing `dict` content. The key is to calculate the value based on the variable type.

Note that this does not take into account the situations when the var is a `list` which will be replaced as all other type of values. This will not either deal with type mismatch between existing vars and config map. e.g. if your existing var is `string` and the corresponding one in config map a `dict` it will break.

The following playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    cm_config:
      label1: toto
      label2:
        a_value: 1
        other_value: 2
      label3:
        a_value: 3
        other_value: 4
      label4: tata

    label1: I am set in play
    label3:
      some_value: I'm a poor lonesome cowboy

  tasks:
    - name: show initial state
      debug:
        var: "{{ item.key }}"
      with_dict: "{{ cm_config }}"

    - name: Process values from config map
      vars:
        my_value: >-
          {% if item.value is mapping %}
          {{ lookup('vars', item.key, default={}) | combine(item.value) }}
          {% else %}
          {{ item.value }}
          {% endif %}
      set_fact:
        "{{ item.key }}": "{{ my_value }}"
      with_dict: "{{ cm_config }}"

    - name: Show the result after processing config map
      debug:
        var: "{{ item.key }}"
      with_dict: "{{ cm_config }}"
```

gives the following result:

```
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [show initial state] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=label1) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "label1",
        "value": "toto"
    },
    "label1": "I am set in play"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=label2) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "label2",
        "value": {
            "a_value": 1,
            "other_value": 2
        }
    },
    "label2": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=label3) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "label3",
        "value": {
            "a_value": 3,
            "other_value": 4
        }
    },
    "label3": {
        "some_value": "I'm a poor lonesome cowboy"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=label4) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "label4",
        "value": "tata"
    },
    "label4": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [Process values from config map] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'label1', 'value': 'toto'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'label2', 'value': {'a_value': 1, 'other_value': 2}})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'label3', 'value': {'a_value': 3, 'other_value': 4}})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'label4', 'value': 'tata'})

TASK [Show the result after processing config map] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=label1) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "label1",
        "value": "toto"
    },
    "label1": " toto "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=label2) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "label2",
        "value": {
            "a_value": 1,
            "other_value": 2
        }
    },
    "label2": " {'a_value': 1, 'other_value': 2} "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=label3) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "label3",
        "value": {
            "a_value": 3,
            "other_value": 4
        }
    },
    "label3": " {'some_value': \"I'm a poor lonesome cowboy\", 'a_value': 3, 'other_value': 4} "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=label4) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "label4",
        "value": "tata"
    },
    "label4": " tata "
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```